# Automator turning well-aligned PDF documents upside-down, flipped -- unreadable in OSX?

Tags: macos, pdf, automator, bug

[image]

I have PDFs that are readable. When I combine the PDFs, the pages go randomly up-side-down and left-and-right. I have fixed this issue manually in Preview app but I would like to get the pages as they are originally in their documents. How can I get the PDFs right-combined i.e. readable?

Answer (score 1):

It must be how you have the PDFs that you want to combine. I have this exact same workflow as an app and it works great and perfectly. However if you have several PDFs that are not all the same orientation then it will do what is happening.

I don't see any other way of doing it other then manually opening up each one in Preview and using Command L or R to change the right orientation.

Phil

Comment: This must be a bug in handling PDFs, PDFs are all right aligned but Automator changes their orientation.

Comment: Weird. Okay. 'cause when I do it -- it works perfectly. Sorry I am not sure what the bug is.

Comment: Many PDFs are broken even though it does not look so. It may have something to do with it.